# What is a Waiting Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word™/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+phrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Word%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule I call it a Waiting Word™.  Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Waiting Words™ | Not Waiting Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| AN | A |
| FEEL | TOUCH |
| FOOTSTOOL | STOOL |
| GNAW | CHEW |
| MOM | DAD |
| OUTDO | OUTLAST |
| POP | SNAP |
| ROTOR | WHEEL |
| SEXES | GENDERS |
| SIS | BRO |
| TAINT | DEFILE |

CSV version:

```
Waiting Words™,Not Waiting Words™
AN,A
FEEL,TOUCH
FOOTSTOOL,STOOL
GNAW,CHEW
MOM,DAD
OUTDO,OUTLAST
POP,SNAP
ROTOR,WHEEL
SEXES,GENDERS
SIS,BRO
TAINT,DEFILE
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A Waiting Word™ is...

> a palindrome (including spaces) in Morse code.
>
> ```
>     AN       :  .- -.
>     FEEL     :  ..-. . . .-..
>     FOOTSTOOL:  ..-. --- --- - ... - --- --- .-..
>     GNAW     :  --. -. .- .--
>     MOM      :  -- --- --
>     POP      :  .--. --- .--.
>     ROTOR    :  .-. --- - --- .-.
>     SEXES    :  ... . -..- . ...
>     SIS      :  ... .. ...
>     TAINT    :  - .- .. -. -
> ```

Comment: That was quick!

Comment: Why's it called a Waiting Word?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry As far as I can tell, WAITING is just another example of a word which fits this palindromic pattern. No idea if 'wait' is anything to do with the pauses in the code transmission??